# using VS2010 Crystal Report draw graph from XML

Tags: xml, graph, crystal-reports-2010

I want to use VS2010 crystal report to create a report with at least one graph, and the data to plot graph is from XML file.

At this point, I am able to:
-Plot graph from XML (using VS2010 not crystal report)
-Using crystal report display data from XML file.

Is there a way to do it? Is there any tutorial for similar task?

I tried to find solution for many days but still cannot find a solution that able to solve the problem, hope someone can point me how should I do it (I mean method, steps, etc.)

p.s. I'm using C#.